# Cannot run mysql on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am having a hard time running mysql on ubuntu 21.04.
I tried:

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server
sudo apt purge mysql-server
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt remove dbconfig-mysql
```

and

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* mysql-client-core-*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

before reinstalling mysql-server with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

but to no avail.
The problem is that when I install I get this in the terminal:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when I run `sudo mysql`, I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

and when I run `systemctl status mysql` I get:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit mysql.service failed to load properly: Device or resource busy.)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-09-05 23:29:27 EET; 58min ago
   Main PID: 31191 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
```

I tried:

```
sudo systemctl stop  mysql
sudo systemctl start  mysql
```

but I get

```
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service failed to load properly: Device or resource busy.
See system logs and 'systemctl status mysql.service' for details.
```

in error.log I get:

> 2021-09-05T22:26:37.674376Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start
> server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use

> 2021-09-05T22:26:37.674517Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you
> already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?

> 2021-09-05T22:26:37.674808Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

But when I run `netstat -lp | grep 3306` I see that nothing is running on port 3306. And I reassure that by running  `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3306)`

Any Idea on how to solve this?

Comment: try one of these from the start https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fix-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1#

Comment: @nbk Thank you very much for your response. I actually have already found this article while surfing and I did try every method in it, but unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: even the force removal of the package? maybe ask ubuntu can hwlp you further